# hook_theme() does not pass arguments

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I currently write a module that generates a block. The output should be defined by a template. Nothing special, yet the arguments don't seem to get passed properly.

This is the theme-method:

```
/* # Theme {{{*/
function browse_by_taxonomy_theme() {
  return array(
    'browse_by_taxonomy_block' => array(
      'template' => 'browse_by_taxonomy_block',
      'arguments' => array(
        'next' => null,
        'previous' => null,
        'term' => null,
        'hide_if_null' => variable_get('browse_by_taxonomy_hide_links', false)
      )
    )
  );
}/*}}}*/
```

And it's being called like that:

```
$block['content'] = theme('browse_by_taxonomy_block', "next", "previous", $tid);
```

Even when i put it to the minimum of this it does not work:

```
function browse_by_taxonomy_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {  
  switch ($op) {
    case 'list':
      $block = array(array('info' => t("Browse by taxonomy")));
      return $block;

    case 'view':
      # […] Dragons be here
      return array(
        'subject' => null, 
        'content' => theme('browse_by_taxonomy_block', "next", "previous", "p")
      );
  }
}/*}}}*/
```

But in my template *everything* is `null`

```
var_dump($previous); # => NULL
var_dump($next); # => NULL
var_dump($hide_if_null); # => NULL
var_dump($term); # => NULL
```

In another module i wrote i did it pretty much the same way and it works. What am I doning wrong this time?

Comment: It must comes from something else in the module because this looks fine, it should work.

Comment: Are the variables defined using `get_defined_vars()`?

Comment: @wildpeaks even my minified version with every magic stripped out does not work.

Comment: @googletorp nope, none of my arguments is inside of get_defined_vars();

Comment: @Nils, My best guess would be that it's cache related, because the code looks fine. Have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: @nils: What theme are you using?

Comment: @googletorp … oh my god … it was the cache -.-" Could you post it as an answer, so i can mark this as answered?

Comment: if you flushed drupal cache?
Where template is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the problem is caused by caching issues, as Drupal caches all theme info for performance reasons.

Answer (score -1):

Caching is the devil in this case my frend... just refresh your theme and it will most likely work. That was the thing in my case atleast, after a long long long search filled with lots of cursing and swearing I finally tried that and BINGO...